# Is it possible to reset a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have access to a Jupyter Notebook that was created as a learning tool for some code - so the idea is just to play around and see what changing different things does.

I played around, but now I want to reset everything back to how it was before I started editing it. As I can't see an easy way to do this, I'm guessing that I'm thinking of it all the wrong way.

Is it not possible to reset the book? If not, why not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `%reset -f` in a code cell.

This will reset all variables and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcuts in an open notebook. Find the option for clear all cells output

Add a shortcut such as Ctrl-C